# Solr : Server refused connection at: http://localhost:xxxx/solr/collectionName

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have two Solr nodes running in cloud mode. I know that we send queries and updates directly to Solr's collection e.g.http://host: port/solr/. Any of the Solr nodes can be used. If the node does not have the collection being queried then the request will be forwarded internally to a Solr instance which has that collection.

But, my question is what happens when the node being queried is down. I am getting this 
error: Server refused connection at http://localhost:xxxx/solr/collectionName.

Does not Zookeeper handle this scenario?

Everything is fine when the node being queried is running. I am able to index and fetch data.

Comment: What Solr library are you using? If you're giving it a direct Solr URL - and not the connection info for ZK - how can it know where to connect?

Comment: I did use CloudSolrClient to query or index data. I did not have to check which Solr node is active. The problem I am facing during bulk indexing is that the Zookeeper runs out of connections resulting in Connection Timeout error. 

How can I get to know in advance the active Solr nodes? Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: I could get the live Solr nodes using this piece of code


    ZkStateReader zkStateReader = client.getZkStateReader();
    ClusterState clusterState = zkStateReader.getClusterState();
    Set<String> liveNodes = clusterState.getLiveNodes();


This way, I will be able to send a query to one of the live nodes and Zookeeper will take care of the rest, but, I was wondering if this is a good practice to query from SolrCloud.

What if the Solr node goes down in the middle of bulk indexing.